# How can I write a Java directory chooser?

Tags: java, directory

How can I write a directory chooser as like that:

[image]

or:
[image]

at Java?

**PS 1:** I am developing a desktop application and I use Swing at my application.

**PS 2:** I want to list just directories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a TreeTable, here's a directory scanner using a treetable with a pretty decent tutorial: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/

Your second picture looks just like JFileChooser...

```
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(file);
      fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

If you want to change it's behavior just create a MyFileChooser class that extends JFileChooser.